# Unable to access my web2py app login page by running docker container using gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine, docker, web2py

I am new to docker, I'm trying to run my web2py app using docker container in gae, my Dockerfile create the docker image, below is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER john
#install python
RUN apt-get install -y -qq wget python unzip
#install GAE
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/google-cloud-sdk.zip && unzip google-cloud-sdk.zip && rm google-cloud-sdk.zip
RUN google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=true --path-update=true --bash-completion=true --rc-path=/.bashrc --additional-components app-engine-python
ENV PATH /google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR Testapp
COPY Testapp .
RUN pwd
#Expose the ports
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["dev_appserver.py", "--host=0.0.0.0", "."]
```

the above dockerfile is created the image and its running by using

```
$ docker run -it --rm -p 9090:9090 registry.local/python
INFO     2015-12-17 10:54:47,049 devappserver2.py:769] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2015-12-17 10:54:47,248 simple_search_stub.py:1126] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/appengine.testapp.root/search_indexes
```

and I'm tried to access the my application using http://localhost:8080 but i got the This webpage is not available so i change the port number as 9090 and `CMD ["dev_appserver.py", "--host=10.10.10.60", "."]`

as per my ip r but i got the google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind 10.10.10.60:8080 what is the issue here

Comment: FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER John
#install python
RUN apt-get install -y -qq wget python unzip
#install GAE
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/google-cloud-sdk.zip && unzip google-cloud-sdk.zip && rm google-cloud-sdk.zip
RUN google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=true --path-update=true --bash-completion=true --rc-path=/.bashrc --additional-components app-engine-python
ENV PATH /google-cloud-sdk/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR DFSA_Testapp
COPY DFSA_Testapp .
RUN pwd
#CMD python web2py.py
#Expose the ports
EXPOSE 9090
CMD ["dev_appserver.py", "--host=0.0.0.0", "."]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're probably not binding the port to your host -- try running the container with `-p 8080:8080` and then hitting `http://localhost:8080` again (otherwise `localhost:8080` won't be hitting your container).

Comment: I'm using "docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 image_name." with -p but not working

Comment: Are you using OS X + boot2docker, or is this running locally directly on a Linux host?  If you're using boot2docker / Docker Machine / Docker Toolbox, you'll need to hit the VM's IP address (usually available via "docker-machine ip your-machine" or "docker-machine ip default").

Comment: I'm using vagrant in my windows Machine and I'm running locally

Comment: Ok then your best bet is going to be to get the IP address of the Vagrant VM, and try hitting that instead.

Comment: yeah, i tried with 10.10.10.60:8080 IP address of the Vagrant VM. But not working

Comment: You're still running dev_appserver.py with --host=0.0.0.0, right?  Otherwise it won't be listening on the correct IP address in order to be reachable from outside the container.

Comment: Right I'm running dev_appserver.py with --host=0.0.0.0, if i change it as 10.10.10.60 and running the container i am facing the "google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.wsgi_server.BindError: Unable to bind 10.10.10.60:8080"

Comment: By running dev_appserver.py with --host=0.0.0.0 i am not getting the above error but the $ docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 registry.local/python
WARNING  2015-12-14 12:06:46,089 simple_search_stub.py:1126] Could not read search indexes from /tmp/appengine.testapp.root/search_indexes
INFO     2015-12-14 12:06:46,104 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:47882
INFO     2015-12-14 12:06:46,239 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
INFO     2015-12-14 12:06:46,247 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000